# Mocking mixin in Vue Test libs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils, vue-testing-library

I'm having a couple of issues with my Vue test libs. I am trying to test a mixin. It requires setting the route and mocking a function.  Here is my code

MIXIN

```js
export const CampaignNotifier = {
    mounted () {
        // Create tagname with dynamic currency parameter from banking app
        let routeName = this.$route.name
        let queryParamCurrency = (this.$route.query.currency) ? `- ${ this.$route.query.currency.toUpperCase() }` : '-'
        this.campaignTagName = (BRAZE_TAG_MAPPING[routeName]) ? BRAZE_TAG_MAPPING[routeName].replace(/-/, queryParamCurrency) : null
        if (this.campaignTagName) {
            this.$appboy.logCustomEvent(this.campaignTagName)
        }
    },
}
```

TEST:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import { CampaignNotifier } from '@/mixins/campaignNotifier'

let wrapper

function factory (routeName, currency) {
    let localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(VueRouter)

    let routes = [
        {
            path: routeName,
            name: routeName,
            query: {
                currency
            }
        }
    ]

    let router = new VueRouter({
        routes
    })

    let Component = {
        render () { },
        mixins: [CampaignNotifier],
        localVue,
        router,
        mocks: {
            $route: {
                path: routeName,
                query: {
                    currency
                }
            },
            $appboy: {
                logCustomEvent: () => {}
            }
        }
    }
    return shallowMount(Component)
}

describe('@/mixins/campaignNotifier', () => {
    it('Campaign Notifier is not called if route not configured correctly', () => {
        wrapper = factory('before-begin', 'EUR')
        console.log('$route ***', wrapper.vm.$route)

        sinon.spy(wrapper.vm.$appboy, 'logCustomEvent')
        expect(wrapper.vm.$appboy.logCustomEvent).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

Issues I am encountering:

1. When I mock the $route and console.log it, it returns `undefined`.  I tried mocking it and also using VueRouter. Neither worked.
2. I am trying to mock the global prototype / method `$appboy.logCustomEvent` I get:
   [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'logCustomEvent' of undefined"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly combining [mounting options](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mounting-options) with the component definition itself, so your mocks aren't actually getting installed, leading to the errors you observed.

Mounting options should be passed as the [second argument to `shallowMount`](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount):

```js
function factory() {
  let Component = {
    render() { },
    mixins: [CampaignNotifier],
  }
  let mountingOptions = {
    localVue,
    router,
    mocks: {
      $route: {
        path: routeName,
        query: {
          currency
        }
      },
      $appboy: {
        logCustomEvent: () => { }
      }
    }
  }
  return shallowMount(Component, mountingOptions)
}
```